# JavaScript loop - Ajax image animation asp.net MVC

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, for-loop, dicom

My application is asp.net MVC, I am using the following script to change Z axis of a 3D image and display the resulted images as animation:

```
  for (var i = 1; i < 202 * sThickness; i++) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Home/Rotate3D',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        pX: 0,
                        pY: 0,
                        pZ: i * sThickness,
                        udm: ++udm
                    },
                    success: function () {
                        dicom1.src = '<%=Url.Action("Rotate3DImage")%>';
                      //  alert(i);
                    },
                    error: function () {
                    }
                });
```

The first action in the controller "Rotate3D":

```
public ActionResult Rotate3D(float pX = 0, float pY = 0, float pZ = 0, int inc = 0)
    {
        DicomImage3D im = null;
        im = MySession.Current.mpr as DicomImage3D;
        im.SetViewPlane(new Point3D(pX, pY, pZ), new Vector3D(0, 0, 1), new Vector3D(0, 1, 0));
        MySession.Current.dicomImage = im;
        return Json(new { success = true, inc = inc }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

The second action to make the image:

```
 public ActionResult Rotate3DImage()
    {
        FileContentResult data;
        Image objImage = null;
        DicomImage3D im = null;
        im = MySession.Current.dicomImage as DicomImage3D;
   ......;
        using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            objImage.Save(memStream, ImageFormat.Png);
            data = this.File(memStream.GetBuffer(), "image/png");
        }
        return data;
    }
```

I works but does not display each image just jump to the last image, when I added alert, I get 127!!  Any suggetions, thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you working on a healthcare application? Something to do with viewing medical images? Lets hope not :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding done as follows:

```
  .........
   }).done(function(d) {
  dicom1.src = '/Home/Rotate3DImage?udm=' + (++udm);
  layer1.draw();
  });
```